# Pinning ag-grid footer row

Tags: ag-grid

Is there a way to pin the Ag-Grid footer (via `groupIncludeTotalFooter`) to the bottom of the grid?
I looked for this in the documentation but I could not find a solution to do it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

As of Ag-Grid 27.0.0, it appears that this is not yet possible with the built-in `groupIncludeTotalFooter` [feature](https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grouping-footers/#top).  I found a feature request logged as `AG-1960` in Ag-Grid's [development pipeline](https://www.ag-grid.com/pipeline/).

This [Ag-Grid GitHub issue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1791) also provides more information.

The only alternative at the moment seems to use the [Row Pinning feature](https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-pinning/) and calculate the total row data on your own.